# Magento 2 giving error while creating New Module In PathValidator.php line 63:

Tags: magento2, module

I am creating a new module in Magento 2 
when I run the command

`bin/magento module:enable Module_Name`

it's giving following error

Path "/var/www/vhosts/magento2-blank/app/etc/" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/vhosts/magento2-blank/app/etc/"

can anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give writable permissions to `app/etc`. Since you are enabling the new module, your `config.php` file must have write permission to do changes which reside in `app/etc` directory. 
Please run the command.

> chmod -R 777 app/etc/